How can I delete associated models in Gorm?
I'm facing a problem with deleting ModelA along with its associated ModelB instances using Gorm's soft delete methods. Here's a simplified version of my code:
type ModelA struct {
  gorm.Model
  ModelAID uint

  // Association
  ModelBs []ModelB `gorm:"foreignKey:ModelAID"`
}

type ModelB struct {
  gorm.Model
  ModelA_ID uint
  ModelA    ModelA `gorm:"foreignKey:ModelAID"`
}

And this is how I attempted to delete ModelA and its associations:
db.Select(clause.Associations).Delete(&gcs_models.GcsAcademicYear{}, request.ID)

Unfortunately, this approach doesn't seem to work as expected. Any insights or suggestions on how to properly delete both ModelA and its associated ModelB instances using Gorm's soft delete methods would be greatly appreciated.
